# HibernateException with setTimestamp but works with setParameter

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's a minimal version of the code that took me a lot of time to figure out why it's not working:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(queryString);
q.setTimestamp(0, new java.util.Date());
```

The error was:

```
Unset positional parameter at position: 0
```

When I replaced `setTimestamp()` with `setParameter()`:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(queryString);
q.setParameter(0, new java.util.Date());
```

And it worked, but I can't figure out why. I'm using hibernate 3.2.1.

**EDIT:** Where did the post with the other suggestion go? This was it!!

Comment: what does your query string look like?

Comment: It was `"from Applications s where s.validUntil between ? and ?"` (HQL). Both were actually from a `Calendar` object using `cal.getTime()` but to keep it simple, I just included one bare `Date` object. The error stays the same both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a answer here previously that suggested to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.util.Date`. With this little modification, the `setTimestamp` method works as expected.

Comment: Timestamp is deprecated as of JDK 1.1

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping you may need to add the following annotation to your variable that is holding the Timestamp

`@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

That could be why `setParameter` is working (it just takes an object) and `setTimestamp` is not.

Comment: I don't think that this is it. The field is type `timestamp` already. Otherwise I doubt it would work with `setParameter()` either.

Comment: Not necessarily. Without @Temporal annotation, the field is treated as a DATE by Hibernate. When calling setParameter, you bind a Date instance to a field of type DATE. Everything is OK. With setTimestamp, you bind a Timestamp object to a DATE field. That's not the same thing. Have you at least tried this solution?